# Is it possible to remove blank lines from js in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, code-formatting

[image: option doesnt work]

Is it possible to remove empty lines from ES6 js code? IDEA formatter spoils my codestyle :(

Comment: You can always use a regexp for that, just be careful with multiline strings. Btw, the suggested spaced style is preferred in most style guides, there's no wonder it is lobbied by IDE. It is always easier to adopt commonly accepted style than to go against the stream (saying this from my own experience).

Comment: It would make sence if I could extent CTRL-ALT-L

Comment: I'm quite sure it is possible with a macro that combines original ctrl-alt-l and `(\r?\n)+` replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22783), feel free to vote/comment.

Comment: Thanx! But its hanging there for half a year, probably will never be fixed as usual...

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get rid of the blanks using the regex `^\s*^`. Press replace in the html/js directory or the individual file and the blank spaces are gone. Here is a [perma](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206344569/comments/115000365190) from IntelliJ support.